# How to parse “That is ADJ which VP”?

Tags: grammaticality

I was reading this [Etymonline entry](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=mutual&searchmode=none) which cited the following, whose syntax confuses me:

> [1.] ***That*** is **common** `which` pertains equally to two or more persons or things.
>   [2.] ***That*** is **mutual** `which` is freely interchanged: mutual love, affection, hatred. [...]
>   [J.H.A. Günther, "English Synonyms Explained & Illustrated," Groningen, 1904]

3. In both [1], [2.], does the relative pronoun `which` refer to the demonstrative pronoun ***That***?
I'm guessing that    ***That*** is **{adjective}**    is the main clause.
The subordinate clause starting with `which`   is a relative clause.

4. Should  ***That***  be replaced with:  ALL ***That***  ?

Comment: "*That which* is common pertains to..." can be reordered to "*that* is common *which* pertains to...".   In other words, "That [the thing] which is 'common' pertains to..." or "That [the thing] is 'common' which pertains to..."  The word "that" is being used as demonstrative pronoun.

Comment: When offering the definition of a word, there is no *grammatical* need to say "*All* things which are 'raw' are uncooked".  We understand the definition is meant to apply generally when a *metonymic* definition is given: "*Something* which is 'raw' is uncooked" or "*A thing* that is 'raw' is uncooked" or "That which is 'raw' is uncooked" or "That is 'raw' which is uncooked".

Answer (score 1):

Here Günther is contrasting the words *common* and *mutual*. The excerpt “That is common which *X*” can be paraphrased as any of

- That which *X* can be called common
- Things that *X* rate description as common
- To say that a thing is common means that the thing *X*.

All four versions mean essentially the same thing.

The construction is roughly parallel to (1) *He is rich who has a loving wife*, which can be rearranged to (2) *He who has a loving wife is rich*. Note that as the parallel with (1) illustrates, Günther’s *that* is a pronoun, but not demonstrative. The structures of (1) and (2) and the one Günther uses are archaic, and at best quite rare.

Speaking of Günther’s sentence, its subject is *that which X*, and its predicate is *is common*.

Given the name *Günther*, it is reasonable to suppose that the author was a German speaker, and it may be the case his wording reflects syntax that’s more common in that language.